# Creating controls dynamically using xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a list of objects in my application using which I want to create Wrappanels dynamically. One way is to write control adding in code behind as below.

```
WrapPanel RuleInternalCond = new WrapPanel();

// Create operator combo box and fill all operators
ComboBox operatorCb = new ComboBox();
operatorCb.Items.Add("OR");
operatorCb.Items.Add("AND");

RuleInternalCond.Children.Add(operatorCb);
```

But is there a better way to create a template of the wrap panel, bind it to my properties and use my collection in xaml to create list of wrap panel templates automatically?

To explain in detail.
I want to create an wrap panel with controls in xaml which bind to properties. But the problem comes if I want a list of these wrap panels to be created dynamically depending on my collection. For eg my collect is

List = new List
where MyRules is

String Name;
String Condition;

I want the List Item to be in WrapPanel with TextBox of Name and Condition

Comment: Simple answer: YES. Further: It is not clear what you are asking. Can you show a second element and state clearly which parts should be _dynamic_

Comment: Well you could dynamically generate the xaml and use `System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load`

Comment: if this is an `ObservableCollection` then use `ListView` or `ListBox` or any other `ItemsControl`, then define `DataTemplate` for each item in the collection. If however the collection is not an `ObservableCollection` then use `CollectionViewSource` IN XAML. it will use the collection that doesn't implement INPC. HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a code sample for using an ItemsControl. I am assuming you use an object that has those 2 properties and you need to use an ObservableCollection like @XAMIMAX wrote in the comment    (`ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyList` ).

```
           <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Condition}"/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I just got it - I had not put get and set on the observableCollection<MyObject>. Thanks a lot for your help.